# DispHTMLDivElement in Quirks is now HTMLDivElement in IE9,Method TransformNode not defined

Tags: javascript, jsp, internet-explorer

My Problem is we are upgrading our clients site to IE9,IE10, IE11 and we have lots of javascript issues.  First to IE9.
One issue is, in code we have 2 `div`s in a jsp.
There is XML and xsl included in the same jsp and the transformed output is to shown in other div.

In Jsp

```
<div class="someData" id="div1"></div>
<div class="scrollbox" style="width:930px; height:197px" id="div2"></div>
```

In Js

```
document.all["div2"].innerHTML.XMLDocument.transformNode(xslData.documentElement)
```

For Quirks mode the `div1` element is rendered as `DispHTMLDivElement`, which has `transformNode` method.
But in IE9 it is rendered as `HTMLDivElement` and hence method not supported error occurs.
Is there a way by which I can convert the `HTMLDivElement` to `DispHTMLDivElement`.
I tried searching in internet but was not able to find much information about `DispHTMLDivElement`.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced same kind of issue while migrating from IE 7 to higher version.
what i observe was the level of hierarchy and abstraction has been changed now .
So in your case you can try that :

```
document.all["div2"][0].innerHTML.XMLDocument.transformNode(xslData.documentElement)
```

I hope that will work.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to add in the header:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8;">
...
```

in order to force IE8 rendering even in IE9+ ?